# Best way to map inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Junior developer trying to spice us his portfolio..:

I am making a rest api as a personal project for insurancebrokers where they can store information about their clients and the contracts etc.
An insurance contract obviously has something that it insures (for example car / property/...).
So those classes are some kind of riskobject.

What is the best way to implement this using Spring & Hibernate without making a serviceclass for each of those subtypes (and another endpoint aswell)?

I ran into a similar problem with the client part (which can be either a person or a company) and used composition for that one because there were only 2 possibilities however for the riskobjects there are way more possible subclasses and thus this might not be ideal or is it the best possible way?

Code of insurance class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Insurance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String contractNumber;
    @ManyToOne
    private InsuranceCompany insuranceCompany;
    @ManyToOne
    private Client policyHolder;
    @ManyToOne
    private Riskobject object;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDate createdOn;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDate updatedOn;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endingDate;
    private Periodicity periodicity;
    private double cost;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
    private Duration duration;
    private boolean active = true;
```

the type would specify wether its a car/property/liability/... insurance and based on that I'd need to give the possibility to make a certain kind of subclass because I'd want to avoid giving the possibility to make a car object in a property insurance for example.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: You may consider using composition over inheritance in this case, saving the headache overall

Answer (score 0):

JPA supports the concept of a "Discriminator", a column that tells how to map the data for inheritance.

There is a good look at it here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a "brute" approach, have just one, generic class, keep all possible properties inside, and allow those which do not apply to be null. Thats less work setting up, might be more work sorting through the data. Performance wise...well we live in age where we stream video etc., some unnecessary null properties wont be probably a big hit.